# Picker onValueChange() called twice

Tags: react-native, expo, i18next, react-i18next

I want to support localization using react-18next.
This component shows a `Picker`, sets a LocalStorage key (the selected language) and change the app language.
I noticed the `onValueChange` method is called twice. The first call (using a proper selection tap action on a Picker item) have the correct parameter (the language I have chosen), the second call have the value of the first Picker item, whenever the values is (!).

**Example**: if I select the `English` Picker item, I see the Picker switch to English (first `_changeLanguage()` call), and then again to "Device" (second `_changeLanguage()` call). I'm sure it's an async ops problem, not sure where..

```
@translate(['settings', 'common'], { wait: true })
export default class Settings extends Component {
    state = {};
     constructor(props)  {
        super(props);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.getLang();
    }

    async _changeLanguage(ln) {
        const { t, i18n, navigation } = this.props;
        console.warn("_changeLanguage: ",ln)
        await this.promisedSetState({lang:ln})
        if(ln=="device") {
                console.warn("removing lang setting")
                await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@App:lang');
        } else {
                console.warn("lang setting: ", ln)
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('@App:lang', ln);
                i18n.changeLanguage(ln) 
        }

    };
    //get Language from AsyncStorage, if it has been previously set
    async getLang() {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@App:lang');
        console.warn("getLangfrom asyncstorage:", value)
        if(value) await this.promisedSetState ({lang:value})
    }

    promisedSetState = (newState) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.setState(newState, () => {
                resolve()
            });
        });
    };
    render() {
        const { t, i18n, navigation } = this.props;
        const { navigate } = navigation;

        return (<View>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={this.state.lang}
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>this._changeLanguage(itemValue) }>
                        <Picker.Item color="#666" label="detected from device" value="device" />
                        <Picker.Item label="English" value="en" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Deutsch" value="it" />

                    </Picker>
                </View>);
    }
}
```

The code is based on the react-i18next Expo example
https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/v9.x.x/reactnative-expo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around the react-native Picker seems bugged.

This quickfix solved my problem https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13351#issuecomment-450281257

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if this belongs here but if anyone is encountering the problem of `onValueChange` firing twice and is using `react-native-picker-select` instead of the default `Picker` then this solution may work for you.

I ended up using the `itemKey` property instead of `value` and setting the key of each item to be the same as its value. Note the example item would end up shaped like so: `{ key: 'value1', value: 'value1', label: 'Your Label' }` where the `key` and `value` are identical.

Original Code:

```js
<RNPickerSelect
   style={styles.picker}
   value={value}
   onValueChange={this.onValueChange}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   items={options}
/>
```

Fixed Code:

```js
<RNPickerSelect
   style={styles.picker}
   itemKey={value}
   onValueChange={this.onValueChange}
   placeholder={placeholder}
   items={options}
/>
```

I got my inspiration from this: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/265).

Comment: This certainly belongs here, because google landed me here and your solution fixed my problem!